# Drupal page is not found error is showing

Tags: routes

I am working on a project where I created a custom module to store data into database from a form. It is working fine. But now I am working on how to fetch the data from database and show the data in another page.
The following is the code in my .module file:

```
function request_by_user_menu() {
  $items = array();
//added for fetch and show data from database in request_by_user_menu().not working

 $items['example/submit'] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
    'title' => 'Form Data', //page title
    'description' => 'Show data from database.',
    'page callback' => 'request_by_user_show', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
   'access callback' => TRUE
  );
  return $items;
}

/*//function for fetch and show data from database.Not working.*/
 function request_by_user_shown(){
     $results=db_query("SELECT * FROM {request_by_user}");
     $header=array(t('ID'),t('Number'));
     $rows=array();
     foreach($results AS $result){
         $rows[]=array(
         $result->uid,
         $result->passwd,
         );
     }
     return theme('table', array('header' => $header,'rows' => $rows));
 }
```

When I am opening 'example/submit' it is showing "page not found" error.

Comment: I think it is not a  duplicate of the post.

Comment: Then it would be useful to add that your question why that is. :) Currently I don't see any reason why it would not be. :)

Comment: If you already tried the steps shown in the question @Letharion linked, tell us at which step it stopped to work, for example. That way we'll know you did as much own research as you could be reasonably expected to do :) The point of "generic" questions and answers is to give you all some guidelines and steps to take, so we will not need to tell the same thing over and over. When we'll see you have specific problem with it, we'll be glad to answer it. Oh, and **I don't believe it's worth downvotes.** Come on, people, give this guy a chance!

Comment: ok...Thanks all for your reply and downvoting me...I solved the issue by myself...